# Bluebird.each break if solved

Tags: javascript, for-loop, asynchronous, mongoose, bluebird

I want to test each element of an array until a condition is met then skip the rest. This is the code I came up with, it seems to be working but I'm not sure if its actually safe or it has unexpected side effects. Other solutions are welcomed.

```
let buddyAdded = false;
replicaArr = _.keys(ReplicaList);
Promise.each(replicaArr, function(replicaname) {
  if (!buddyAdded) {
    Player.count({
      'buddyList': replicaname
    }, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {

      } else if (result < 990) {

        Player.update({
          '_id': buddyObj.buddyId
        }, {
          'buddyList': replicaname
        }, function(err) {
          if (err) {

          } else {
            ReplicaList[replicaname].send(buddyObj);
            buddyAdded = true;
            // success stop here and skip all the other  array elements
            return;
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Assuming `Player.count()` and `Player.update()` are async operations, there's no way this works properly.  The callback to `.each()` needs to return a promise that represents the async operations in the callback.  The way you have it, there is no way from outside the callback code to know when it's all done.  Also, since you have Bluebird, you may want to use `Promise.any()` to capture the first value that resolves the way you want.

Comment: To offer you a much better way of doing this, we need to know (in words) exactly what you're trying to accomplish, whether you want to process the array in strict serial order or whether multiple players can be processed in parallel and what exact result you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need to go over an array of available bots and check which of them has room left in its friend list. I use Model.count to get the current number of friends it has in its list. Ideally, it should check them in the order they are in they array. When a bot with empty slots is found, I want to save the bot name to the database, if that operation is successful the promise should be resolved and all the other iteration/elements skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to enumerate the players serially one at a time and abort the iteration when you find a player with room in their buddy list that you can update the list and communicate back any errors that happen, then here's one way of doing it.

Here's how this works:

1. Use Bluebird's `Promise.promisifyAll()` to automatically make promise returning methods for the `Player` object so we can then use those in our control flow.
2. Use Bluebird's `Promise.mapSeries()` to iterate the array serially one at a time.
3. Chain the `Player.countAsync()` and `Player.updateAsync()` methods so they sequence properly and return them from `.mapSeries()` so it waits for them to complete before continuing the iteration to the next array element.
4. If we find a player with room and successfully update its buddy list, then throw a specially exception.  This will reject the current promise chain and cause `.mapSeries()` to stop it's iteration (which is what you said you wanted).
5. Add a `.catch()` at the higher level that tests for the special rejection and turns it into a successful resolved promise.  If it's some other error, then let that continue to propagate as an actual error.

The code:

```
// Promisify the Player object so the methods
// this would usually be done wherever this module is loaded
Player = Promise.promisifyAll(Player);

// create a special subclass of Error for our short circuit
PlayerUpdateDone extends Error {
    constructor(name) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// put logic into a function to make it cleaner to use
function addToBuddyList(replicaArr) {

    return Promise.mapSeries(replicaArr, function(replicaname) {
        return Player.countAsync({buddyList: replicaname}).then(function(result) {
            // if room left in buddy list
            if (result < 990) {
                return Player.updateAsync({'_id': buddyObj.buddyId}, {'buddyList': replicaname}).then(function() {
                    ReplicaList[replicaname].send(buddyObj);
                    // throw special exception to abort .mapSeries()
                    //    and stop further processing
                    throw new PlayerUpdateDone(replicaname);
                });
            }
        });
    }).then(function() {
        // if it gets here, there were no players with rooms so just return null
        return null;
    }).catch(function(result) {
        // we used a special rejection as a shortcut to stop the mapSeries from executing
        //    the rest of the series
        if (result instanceof PlayerUpdateDone) {
            // change this special rejection into a result
            return result.name;
        }
        // must have been regular error so let that propagate
        throw result;
    });
}

// sample usage
addToBuddyList(replicaArr).then(function(name) {
    if (name) {
        console.log(`Updated player ${name}`);
    } else {
        console.log("No players with room in their buddy list");
    }
}).catch(function(err) {
    // error here
    console.log(err);
});
```

---

It may be simpler to make your own sequencer that stops when the first promise resolves to a truthy value:

```
// fn will be passed each array element in sequence
// fn should return a promise that when resolved with a truthy value will stop the iteration
//    and that value will be the resolved value of the promise that is returned from this function
// Any rejection will stop the iteration with a rejection
Promise.firstToPassInSequence = function(arr, fn) {
    let index = 0;

    function next() {
        if (index < arr.length) {
            return Promise.resolve().then(function() {
                // if fn() throws, this will turn into a rejection
                // if fn does not return a promise, it is wrapped into a promise
                return Promise.resolve(fn(arr[index++])).then(function(val) {
                    return val ? val : next();
                });
            });
        }
        // make sure we always return a promise, even if array is empty
        return Promise.resolve(null);
    }
    return next();
};


Promise.firstToPassInSequence(replicaArr, function(replicaname) {
    return Player.countAsync({buddyList: replicaname}).then(function(result) {
        // if room left in buddy list
        if (result < 990) {
            return Player.updateAsync({'_id': buddyObj.buddyId}, {'buddyList': replicaname}).then(function() {
                ReplicaList[replicaname].send(buddyObj);
                return replicaname;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, well explained!, second approach is quite good.