# break from promise mapseries

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have an array of methods and I running them by `Promise.mapSeries`:

```
Promise.mapSeries(functions.map(function => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function(req, res, function(err) {
            if (success) {
                return something(); //if we here, break mapSeries
            }
            resolve();
        });
    })
}))
.then(() => {
    return something();
})
```

How I can break from mapSeries, to prevent execution rest of functions?

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41784895/bluebird-each-break-if-solved

Comment: Yes, but throwing exception or writing custom mapSeries doesn't looks like the best solutions, at all

Comment: `function => { ... }` luckily this ain't valid JS

Comment: why do try to bend `Array#map` to do the work of `Array#some`? `Promise.mapSeries` is supposed to do the work of `Array#map` just with regards to promises and in series

Comment: I need to wait when function executes and then run next.

Comment: Do you need the function calls to be made and wait for the first function succes like race codnition? or make call only if first one failed?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are returning something() you won't execute resolve(); so maybe try to resolve the promise before?

```
Promise.mapSeries(functions.map(function => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          function(req, res, function(err) {
              if (success) {
                  return Promise.resolve(something()); //if we here, break mapSeries
              }
          });
      })
  }))
  .then(() => {
      return something();
  })
```

Comment: you can always try Promise.Reject instead of resolving.